# How can I use linq to return integers in one array that do not match up with an integer property of another array?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following method signature:

```
 internal static int[] GetStudentIDsThatAreNotLinked(PrimaryKeyDataV1[]
       existingStudents, IQueryable<Student> linkedStudents)
```

PrimaryKeyData is a class that has ServerID and LocalID integers as properties.
Student is a class that (among other properties) has an integer one called StudentID.

In English, what I want to do is return an array of integers which are in existingStudents[...].ServerID but not in linkedStudents[...].StudentID

If 'existingStudents' and 'linkedStudents' were both integer arrays, I would use a linq query as below:

```
return from es in existingStudents where
    !linkedStudents.Contains<int>(es) select es;
```

..which could then be converted to an array of ints.

What I want to do is give Contains an IEqualityOperator that will consider a PrimaryKeyData class to be equal to a Student class if PrimaryKeyData.ServerID == Student.StudentID

So I think I need a lambda expression but I'm very confused on how that would be constructed.

I think I'm going in the right direction but can anyone help me over the final hurdle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, my understanding is that you want to get all instances of PrimaryKeyDataV1 whose ServerID property doesn't exist in any of the students.StudentID property of the linkedStudents parameter?

```
internal static PrimaryKeyDataV1[] GetStudentsThatAreNotLinked(PrimaryKeyDataV1[] existingStudents, IQueryable<Student> linkedStudents)
{
    var results = existingStudents.Select(s => s.ServerID)
        .Except(linkedStudents.Select(link => link.StudentID))
        .ToArray();

    return existingStudents.Where(stud => results.Contains(stud.ServerID));
}
```

Or if you just want an array of IDs...

```
internal static int[] GetStudentIDsThatAreNotLinked(PrimaryKeyDataV1[] existingStudents, IQueryable<Student> linkedStudents)
{
    return existingStudents.Select(s => s.ServerID)
        .Except(linkedStudents.Select(link => link.StudentID))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to return the IDs, you can use something like:

```
existingStudents.Select(es => es.StudentID)
              .Except(linkedStudents.Select(ls => ls.ServerID));
```

You can write this in query comprehension form, but I think it's less clear:

```
var result = (from es in existingStudents select es.StudentID);
             .Except
             (from ls in linkedStudents select ls.ServerID)
```

If you need to return the result as an array, just use the `.ToArray()` extension:

```
existingStudents.Select(es => es.StudentID)
              .Except(linkedStudents.Select(ls => ls.ServerID)).ToArray();
```

You don't need to create your own equality comparer in the case that you only need to return the set difference in IDs.

Comment: I appreciate the extra detail on query comprehension but unfortunately, the query returns the linkedstudents that are not in existingstudents but I needed the existingstudents that are not in linkedstudents

Comment: @Neil: My apologies ... I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks and marked up. A shame we can't accept multiple answers as both were pretty much on the money.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<student> ExistingStudents = new List<student>();
    List<student> LinkedStudents = new List<student>();

    ExistingStudents.Add(new student {id=1, name="joe"});
    ExistingStudents.Add(new student { id = 2, name = "beth" });
    ExistingStudents.Add(new student { id = 3, name = "sam" });

    LinkedStudents.Add(new student { id = 2, name = "beth" });


    var students = from stud in ExistingStudents
                    where !(LinkedStudents.Select(x => x.id).Contains(stud.id))
                    select stud;

    foreach(student s in students)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("id: {0}, name: {1}", s.id, s.name));
    }
```

simple student class:

```
public class student
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
```